# Loop detection in connected graph

Tags: loops, detection, cycle

Most example I found only treat single linked lists. I need a solution for a multiple linked list.

Image is easier (valid):

[image]

Invalid:

[image]

Which algorithm would be able to return the begining of the loop (`B`) and not collide with `E`? A good starting point would be also to know if there is a loop at all.
Stuff like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-direct-graph-using-colors/) or edge counting doesn't work (because not single linked...).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if a route from 'end of connection node (B)' to 'start of connection node (C)' exists, if yes, a new loop would be created. Doesn't quite answer it, but good enough...